# How to add the data into object

Tags: angular, typescript

1. I am trying to add the this.filters.season data into this.newQuarters.
2. or I can pass them this.newQuarters and this.filters.season together.
   Please help me to find answer both.

I tried 
this.newQurters.Add(this.filters.season), but didn't work

```
this.filters.season = 1;   
 save = (x) => {
        if (!this.validation(this.newQuarters)) {
            this.seasonQuartersService.save(this.newQuarters).then(r => {
                        this.uiService.toast.success("Saved");
                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: add a key in this.newQuarters and assign this.filters.season to it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.newQuarters["season"]=this.filter.season
```

Comment: Yeah you can use this, if you want to add single data into an object. if you are having multiple values (kind of adding two objects) to add in to a object, you can follow the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `js`,

> `Obj.assign( targetObject, obj1, obj2, .., objn)` method to `copy one object to another`

As far as from your code,`this.newQuaters` is an `OBJECT`and `this.filters` is the `OBJECT` with `season` as one of the `key-value` pair which you have to put into the existing object.

```
const filters = { season : <some_val> }
Object.assign( this.newQuaters, this.filters);
```

For Example,

```
x={a:1,b:2}
y={c:3}
Object.assign(x,y)  // global object
console.log(x) //  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Reference : [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)